# Face API, how to verify a large set of faces in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I have to test the viability of the Face API for our project.
so what I have to test is a set of images of our own faces and they need to be tested against each other. so I've downloaded the python sample from this repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Python and when I run the application and choose "Face Verification" and upload two images it detects both first and then compares them against each other and gives back a confidence grade.

what I'm trying to do is write a script that would check all the images against each other, I was looking through the code where it actually goes through the code that first detects and then verifies for the "Face verification function".

Could someone point me to the code that actually does this, I'm not good with python but my team requires me to use python because they wrote an algorithm that pairs up all images that need to be compared. So what i have to do is run those pairs through detection and run the faceId's that come out of that through the verification function but I don't know how I would go about this. So seeing the code how the sample does it would be a great start.

Answer (score 2):

This repo is deprecated and will be removed soon, please consider the official SDK:
https://pypi.org/project/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-face/

And the samples that comes with it:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-python-sdk-samples/blob/master/samples/vision/face_samples.py

If you have any troubles, any concerns or any questions feel free to open as many questions you want on the Azure SDK for Python repo:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

(I work at Microsoft in the Azure SDK team, and actually I released and wrote the sample for this one :))

Comment: I'm trying to setup the Subscription key env variable but I have no clue how to do it I keep getting this error that I need to set my subscription key, but I have no clue where to do this, in the readme it says "setup the environment variable "some key name"" but nowhere it says how to. Maybe its because I am not familiar with Python but I'm stuck now, I got no clue what to do.

Comment: You want want to read about Environment Variable first: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable. Depending on your shell (bash, powershell, etc.), this is different. This is not a Python concept.